# Keep sending frames through socket in android

Tags: android, sockets, bitmap

I am making an android application that is sending frames from the preview camera continuously from an Android phone to another using TCPIP method.

Right now I can extract the data from the camera using setPreviewCallback method and convert it into Bitmap picture using YUVimage and BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray method.

But the problem is the size of the Bitmap is too big. Even though I compress the bitmap into a small resolution (176*144) and changing the sample size, it will cause out of memory problem when transmitting through socket for several seconds.

I find and try a lot of method but this problem has been stuck for few weeks. Are there any way to reduce the bitmap size or it can be transmit through socket without any errors?

Thanks.

Comment: need more information, how you keep bitmaps, do you kill them right after sending or what. sample code please

Answer (score 0):

Compress the bitmap to JPG before sending.